# how to change data in javascript run in external webpage by userscripts?

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I want to change a object property in a js file run in external webpage.The object
is defined like this:

```
    var OB1{
        transactions: {
            number:100
        }
    };
```

how to change the number' value by userscripts file?

Comment: I want to change the value of number by my userscripts file

Comment: Is `OB1` in a global scope?  Is the `<script>` tag, containing it, external (has a `src` attribute) versus inline?  Link to the target page.  Are you willing to switch to a browser with more power available to the user (Firefox)?  In a large number of cases, this is still not possible in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
OB1["transactions"]["number"] = 200 
OR 
OB1.transactions.number = 200
```

Comment: It will return false log: OB1 is not defined,Because I can only add the codes in my own userscripts file.